# How can we have Flash of Unstyled Content if CSS is render blocking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have heard these two statements:

1. *CSS is render-blocking*
2. *We can have Flash of Unstyled Content*

now the second statement needs rendering and if CSS blocks rendering how can we have such unstyled content?

PS: tag `javascript` added to increase the reach of the question to the web community

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css

Answer (score 0):

You can control CSS Block Render-Blocking

Let's do the merge all the css code in one css file.

Always put your stylessheets in the doucment Head using the link tag

Below Example